# Android Facebook apprequest notification not showing on cell phone

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

I developed an app on android that will send an apprequest to another facebook account and it works well. 
When I open facebook in my computer's browser, it does show a notification that my android app has sent an apprequest. But if I open facebook using the facebook app for android on my phone, I can't see that notification (other notifications such as someone post on my wall still showing so the notification function is working). 
Is that the problem of my code or the apprequest simply can't work on cell phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you use computer's browser and get the Notification in your Facebook profile wall post . then it is successfully posted and works as it has to be.

But if you not able to see that post in your Facebook Mobile app then it is because of the facebook security. Please change the Security of your facebook profile by computer's browser. and then try to see it using facebook mobile app.

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not my case

Comment: @user1417127: Have you solved this issue? As because i am facing the same issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282127/not-able-to-see-app-request-post-from-the-default-facebook-app-or-browser

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the configuration in the app page on facebook. you need to write it as a "mobile web" application on the "base" section.