# Not able to see app request post from the default facebook app or browser

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I am posting the app request to the Friend's wall. It works fine. It shown great with the PC browser. See below image from PC:

[image]

Now while I am going to see the same thing from the Android Device then it is not showing the correct post. I am not able to see the Description and the Some text below it.

See below image from Mobile:

[image]

What's wrong with it ?

Is this problem with my code? If yes then why I am only able to see it from PC?

Answer (score 1):

> I am posting the app request to the Friend's wall.

First of all, that’s not really what’s considered an “app request” with the FB API; it looks like you are posting a mere *link* to your app’s canvas page.

> Now while i am going to see the same thing from the Android Device then it is not showing the correct post. I am not able to see the Description and the Some text below it.

Since canvas/page tab apps are **not available** when accessing Facebook via mobile, Facebook does not display any links that go to canvas/page tabs to users browsing the mobile version.

Comment: So you mean we can not able to see that post in device even if we have set it as canvas page ? Whats the Solution of it ?

Comment: The only possible solution I found so far, is _not_ to link to the app page on Facebook directly – but to a page on your own server, that then does a _redirect_ to your desired Facebook page via JavaScript. Adding the parameter `ref=ts` to a Facebook links makes it stay on the “desktop” version of FB page, even on mobile devices.